# C# and Mantis API, get reproducability

Tags: c#, nusoap, mantis

I am currently working on a project where I will be using Mantisbt's API to integrate bugtracking features into my program, however I have hit a snag.

I used wsdl.exe to generate a c# client library.

I am trying to get the reproducibility, severity, and priority from mantis (preferably in an ObjectRef array) to display it to the end-user so that they may select it from a drop down list.  I managed to get the categories using the following line:

```
this.connector.mc_project_get_categories(username,password,projectid);
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a similar line for the other fields I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [mc_enum_reproducibilities](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl#op.id0x0000000002374b80) . This is preferred to hard-coding your own values, since the MantisBT installation may be customized to have other reproducibilities.

Comment: Ahahah! You're awesome!  Thanks, I don't know how I overlooked that.  That happens to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Reproducibility, severity, priority and similar fields are enumerations in the Mantis PHP files and must be hard-coded in.  The values and text are found in the core/constant_inc.php file.

From these definitions you can create your own ObjectRef to pass.